# Model View Control in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, presentation

Designing a presentation type application which consists of 2 forms, the first form will be used to control the presentation so it can be manipulated on the fly, it will be based off the first monitor of the pc, the second form will be on the second monitor (or projector). I need to update the second form with numbers and pictures during the presentation. In terms of accessing information between forms, would MVC be the best way to do this?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/MVC_intro12122005162329PM/MVC_intro.aspx

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't make it 100% clear if you're are using Forms or WPF (you've put both tags) if you are using WPF the most popular and comfortable design pattern for is generally the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern. Is this is quite close to MVC but slightly different. You can read about it here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

In your application it would mean having data classes that described and manipulated the presentation itself (the model).

Then you would have a view model class (or group of classes) that describe what's visible in each window and the current state of the controls and the currently displayed slide etc. both sets of view models bind to and update the same underlying presentation model.

Finally the XAML and controls render two a 'views' one for each window, the views then become nice and clean binding only to the current state of the ViewModel.

Hope this general outline provides helpful inspiration, if you want and more specific info or advice please ask.

Mark